# Spring Boot scheduled task running for entire hour rather than at the hour

Tags: spring-boot, cron, scheduled-tasks

Spring Boot here. I have the following scheduled task:

```
@Component
public class AdminWatchdog {
    @Autowired
    private EmailService emailService;

    // Ctors, getters & setters here

    @Scheduled(cron = "'* * */12 * * *")
    public void runReports() {
        // Doesn't matter what it does, really
    }
}
```

When I run this, it appears to be firing either every minute or every second (can't tell based on the logs) **for the entire duration of the 12th hour of every day!**

I only want this task to run *one time* every day at noon (12 pm). Is the Spring cron configured incorrectly or do I have something else going on in my app perhaps??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your cron is incorrect. For running your job every noon every day use this

```
"0 0 12 * * ?"
```

The expression is very self explainatory if you understand what each character represent

```
     0          0        12       *            *           ? 
  <second> <minute> <hour> <day-of-month> <month> <day-of-week>
```

For your reference. You can make use of tools like http://www.cronmaker.com/ to design your cron